# How can i automatically add textures to different models

Tags: texturing

When I convert asset to crosa maps, I can just press the texture view button, but when I do the same thing with [Forza Horizon 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forza_Horizon_3) models, it shows up as pink and I go to add the textures but I have to do them individually.

I dont know if the video helps much

[image]

[image]

Comment: This has to do specifically with setting up materials and textures from that game with whatever extractor software you used. A better question might be on how to set up multiple textures via Python, given a certain directory structure and texture channels (diffusion, metalness, luminance, etc. However, you might take a look at https://github.com/thelabcat/SMD-Model-PostImport/blob/main/SMD_material_setup.py for a script I wrote that does this TYPE of thing, though it may not work for you straight off.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: ok ill try that i dont extract it myself i use a website called gamemodels.ru